# iOS / WatchOS - Monitoring the connection between Apple Watch and iPhone

Tags: ios, watchos-2

I am trying to get a notification on iPhone when the connection is lost from my Apple Watch.

My first approach was to check the `session.paired==true` which works fine when the application is on foreground. But I would like to receive that event when the app is on background.

Then I thought about the Background Modes of the iOS and that there is a mode for `external-accessory`that will send a notification on the device when is connected or disconnected. Is there something similar for watchOS?

My other idea is again with background modes and Bluetooth. Can you detect the watchOS as bluetooth?

Did anyone solve this issue?

Comment: You have .reachable and .paired from watch connectivity to check the connectivity, but something like  iBeacon notification (running on background) I am 99.99% sure that´s not possible.

Comment: Is there any way to check in background the .paired? Scheduled task will last only for 10 minutes